# How to pass Array as parameter to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to pass an array and an Id to the controller but every method I have tried gives me null/0 value.

Can someone please help me what's missing in my code?

Here is my JS code:

```
addedParticulars = [{ FundRuleRid: fundRuleRid, FundRuleName: fundRuleName, Amount: amount }] //multiple values


function submitInvoice() {
    if (addedParticulars.length === 0)
        alert('Add any particular first')
    else {
        var jsonObject = JSON.stringify({ fundRules: addedParticulars, flatInvoiceRid: flat_invoice_Rid });
        console.log(jsonObject);
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/FlatInvoice/ProcessInvoiceAmendment",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'JSON', 
            data: jsonObject,
            traditional: true
        });
    }
}
```

This is my Action Method

```
public JsonResult ProcessInvoiceAmendment(List<FundRuleModel> fundRules, Guid flatIinvoiceRid)
{
     return Json(new { status = _requestStatus, message = _responseMessage });
}
```

and this is my .NET class model

```
 public class FundRuleModel : BaseModel
    {
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public Guid FundRuleRid { get; set; }

        public string FundRuleName { get; set; }

        public int FundCycleRid { get; set; }
        public string FundCycleName { get; set; }

        public int FundRuleTypeRid { get; set; }
        public string FundRuleTypeName { get; set; }

        public int FundCalculationTypeRid { get; set; }
        public string FundCalculationTypeName { get; set; }

        public int FlatCalculationFilterRid { get; set; }
        public string FlatCalculationFilterName { get; set; }

        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public DateTime ApplicableDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        public string Narration { get; set; }

        public bool IsIncludedInRegularInvoice { get; set; } = true;

        //Used in FlatInvoiceLogic
        public int Category { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm getting all the values in console but nothing is pass to the controller.

Comment: is there any error in the client (browser) console? check the `Output` window on the server as well. Is your `ProcessInvoiceAmendment` decorated with `HttpPostAttribute`?

Comment: you should create model with "flatIinvoiceRid" property and list of fundRulesand and send only one parameter to your controller

Comment: @Hopeless There is no error neither on client side nor server side

Comment: @barzin.A can't we send two parameters via this method?. Also I have already tried by sending only one parameter (fundRules) but it's not getting the value in controller.

Comment: @OkashaMomin use the `Inspect` tool of your browser, open the `Network` tab, then run your javascript again to capture the request info. It should report the response detail. There must be something wrong.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code on the server side? is it jumping in 
 `ProcessInvoiceAmendment`?

Comment: @Hopeless there is no error in client side. I have checked already. and yes, it's hitting the action method but with the null values.

Comment: in controller before parameter put [FromBody] and in ajax don't need to create object with fundRules name, just stringify your data

Comment: The model binding in asp.net core web api/mvc is a bit different from the ASP.NET MVC. You have to explicitly use `FromBodyAttribute` to apply on one parameter. Because of the way you post your data (json string, `contentType` should be `application/json`), the data should be parsed from the request body (using some `IInputFormatter`), not from Form data (form urlencoded). Because there is just one parameter applicable with `FromBodyAttribute`, the other params can be bound with header, route, querystring only. You can use form urlencoded instead however (so you don't need `JSON.stringify`).

Comment: posting `json string` in the request body should be against a `web api` only. Your browser should however consume a `web mvc` (not a `web api` directly). So you can post `form urlencoded` easily (switching easily between traditional Form and Ajax using jQuery). Exposing `web api` like this to the browser making it stick to just one style of consuming the api (posting the json string), the code also becomes more complicated. What if you need to post data using `<form>`? `web api` is usually consumed by other internal services (including web mvc) & non-browser clients (mobile,desktop apps).

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code using net core mvc, and don't know how it works on another versions:

```
addedParticulars = [{ FundRuleRid: fundRuleRid, 
FundRuleName: fundRuleName, Amount: amount }];

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/FlatInvoice/ProcessInvoiceAmendment/"+flat_invoice_Rid,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.Stringify(addedParticulars),
            success: function (result) {
               ....
            },
            error: function (xhr, exception) {
               .....
            }
           });
```

and change your action to this:

`````
[Route("~/FlatInvoice/ProcessInvoiceAmendment/{flatIinvoiceRid}")]````
public JsonResult ProcessInvoiceAmendment([FromBody] IEnumerable<FundRuleModel> fundRules, string flatIinvoiceRid)
{
Guid  gflatIinvoiceRid= new Guid(flatIinvoiceRid);
......
     return Json(new { status = _requestStatus, message = _responseMessage });
}
`````

Comment: he wants to post a list/array of items, how could this handle that?

Comment: @Sergey I need to post a list/array not just an object

Comment: I added one more way to try.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I found the solutions. Thank to @Sergey and @Hopeless for the help.
Code is working fine without JSON.

I just changed the object format and it's working now;
see the changes below:

```
 var jsonObject = {
            fundRules: addedParticulars ,
            flatIinvoiceRid: flat_invoice_Rid
        };
        console.log(jsonObject);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/FlatInvoice/ProcessInvoiceAmendment",
            data: jsonObject
        });
```

When I added content-type :'application/json' and dataType:'JSON' in ajax it's getting null values on controller (Even after stringifying the object) but when I tried by removing JSON manipulation. It's working fine.